# Understanding c-pointers for rows in 2-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have the following code:

```
int main() {
    int n = 3, m = 4, a[n][m], i, j, (* p)[m] = a;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            a[i][j] = 1;
    p++;
    (*p)[2] = 9;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a hard time understanding what p is here, and the consequences of the operations on p in the end. Can someone give me a brief explanation of what happens. I know c-pointers in their simple settings, but here it get slightly more complicated.

Comment: @Paul consider reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34503/should-the-possible-homework-tag-be-discouraged

Comment: Well, it is an exercise for a group work in Introductionary Programming with Java (and some basic C). I am actually the assistant teacher for the course, but my C is quite more rusty than my Java, so I am just doing the final preparation for the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is an array of `int[m]`, and `p` is a pointer to `int[m]`. It's initialized to `a`, which decays to a pointer to its first element.

Dereferencing `p` yields `int[m]`, which decays to `int*` (pointer to its first element). So `(*p)[2]` adds `2` to the `int*` that was the result of the decay. So it's setting the third of the first `4` integers (`int[m]`, with `m` being 4) to `9`.

Adding to `p` would advance the address stored in it by units of `sizeof(int[m])` bytes, which at runtime (since `m` is not a compile time constant) evaluates to `4 * sizeof(int)`. So `(*(p+1))[2]` would access the third of the second `4` integers. In total, `p` has `3` such arrays of `4` ints to point to: `a+0`, `a+1` and `a+2`.

Notice that you created a C99 VLA, variable length array. You need to `#define` `n` and `m` to integer constants to get rid of those VLAs (which aren't quite portable among C compilers).

Answer (score 2):

`p` is a pointer to a 4-element `int` arrays (i.e. a pointer to pointer to `int`, where the first dimension is 4 and the second is unknown). When you increment `p`, it points to the next 4-element `int` array, i.e. the fifth `int` altogether. Then `p` is dereferenced with offset 2, which means that the seventh `int` changes, so you get

```
  1 1 1 1
  1 1 9 1
  1 1 1 1
```

as the final state of the 4x3 array.

Answer (score 2):

Some small print statements should make clear what this code does:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 3, m = 4, a[n][m], i, j, (* p)[m] = a;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            a[i][j] = 1;

    printf("p points to %u, sizeof(int)*m = %d", p, sizeof(int)*m);
    p++;
    printf(", p++ points to %u\n", p);

    (*p)[2] = 9;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, a[i][j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
p points to 2293536, sizeof(int)*m = 16, p++ points to 2293552
a[0][0] = 1
a[0][1] = 1
a[0][2] = 1
a[0][3] = 1
a[1][0] = 1
a[1][1] = 1
a[1][2] = 9
a[1][3] = 1
a[2][0] = 1
a[2][1] = 1
a[2][2] = 1
a[2][3] = 1
```

Clearly, `p` is a pointer to `int[m]`, so `p++` will advance the pointer to the next row in `a`. That is why `(*p)[2]` will change `a[1][2]`. If you didn't increment `p`, that line would change `a[0][2]`.

Hope that was simple enough!?